# Vue / Vuetify: Search and filter as I type rather than key enter

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I currently have a search setup that when I press enter the search method is called. What I would like to do is rather than lookup the speech is retrieve all results and then filter down matching the search criteria. Any advice?

Search:

```
<v-text-field
  v-model="search"
  @keyup.enter="search"
/>
```

Data:

```
  data () {
    return {
      search: null,
```

Method:

```
search () {
  // search
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a watcher for searchQuery which would trigger search() method each time it's changed.

```
watch: {
    searchQuery: function (value) {
        this.search()
    }
}
```